# Steps to upload file using asp.net send through mobile app

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net, web-services

I have  Mobile applications i.e android, IPhone based in which I have to upload image, on server side I am using asp.net , web service ".asmx".  Now I don't know how to receive file sent by any of the mobile application, or in simple words what I have to do at server side to get that file and store at my local system?  I have tried the following

- I have created a asp.net page where i have placed  control and posted file using `multipart/form-data` , but app developer wants me to give them url with a parameter that will receive file name and then upload it to server.

But how to achieve it ?

Comment: What code have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: using that page i am successfully uploading file if using on browser, but app developers want a url with file name parameter and then upload the file to the server that is what i  am unable to understand how to achieve this?

Comment: or someone can explain me what steps do i have to take if i have to provide a link or url to mobile app developer through which he can upload a file or image on server?

Comment: Fixed some grammer issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved File Upload using WebMethod , both android & Apple applications used this WebMethod for uploading files on server, I tested it using google chrome extension Advanced rest client for reading more about rest API Client [Click Here](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDp_Pat_fKAhXHSY4KHW8iCnoQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.c2E)

```
[WebMethod]
public void UploadFile()
{
    FileResponse master = new FileResponse();
    //HTTP Context to get access to the submitted data
    HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;
    //File Collection that was submitted with posted data
    HttpFileCollection Files = postedContext.Request.Files;
    string sessionId = Server.UrlDecode((string)postedContext.Request.Form["sessionId"]);
    master.sessionId = sessionId;
    master.timeStamp = DateTime.Now.DdMonYyyy_HhMmSs();
    master.status = Status.Failure;
    master.sessionStatus = Status.Failure;
    master.message = "Image not found";
    try
    {
        if (isGuest_Employee(sessionId))
        {
            //Make sure a file was posted
            string fileName = string.Format("feedbackImgSign_{0}.png", Helper.LDFileNumberSeq);
            if (Files.Count == 1 && Files[0].ContentLength >= 1)
            {
                //The byte array we'll use to write the file with
                byte[] binaryWriteArray = new
                byte[Files[0].InputStream.Length];
                //Read in the file from the InputStream
                Files[0].InputStream.Read(binaryWriteArray, 0,
                (int)Files[0].InputStream.Length);
                //Open the file stream
                FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(Helper.UploadedFilesDirectory + "\\" +
                fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                //Write the file and close it
                objfilestream.Write(binaryWriteArray, 0,
                binaryWriteArray.Length);
                objfilestream.Close();

                master.FILE_NAME = fileName;
                master.status = Status.Success;
                master.sessionStatus = Status.Success;
                master.message = "Image uploaded successfully!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            master.status = Status.Failure;
            master.sessionStatus = Status.Failure;
            master.message = "Unable to authenticate provided session Id";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        master.status = Status.Failure;
        master.message = ex.Message;
    }

   string strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(master, Formatting.Indented,
           new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Write(strJSON);
}
```